# How to determine device's location in the sky / project sky coords into 2d map

Tags: geometry, leaflet, gis, geospatial

I am trying to enable a user to point their device into the sky and view the stars where they "should" be located.

I am displaying the stars on a 2d map using LeafletJS and google sky tiles.

The data I have available is the following:

> 1: star ra, dec and mag
>
> 2: gyroscope, compass and accelerator

To get the actual star markers showing on the map I use this formula to convert ra/dec into lat/lng:

```
    starLng = (-(starRa) + 180)
    starLat = starDec
```

I have been banging my head trying to figure out how to project the current area the user is viewing into a 2d leaflet lat/lng and keep track/auto-pan the map depending on which direction the user moves their device.

I am very new to the Celestial coordinate system and all things related.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I know this is possible, because I have seen many apps doing basically the same thing, but I cannot seem to find any information on how to accomplish this.